# How to execute a raw mongodb query in loopback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

How can I execute a raw mongo db query in loopback remote method?
I tried like:

```
    Members.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
          var collection = db.collection('Members');
          var res = collection.find();
          console.log(res);
   });
```

Here, res gives me a huge amount of data inside an object, but I cant find any result documents from that object. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks
!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is async too.

```
    Members.getDataSource().connector.connect(function (err, db) {
          var collection = db.collection('member_col'); //name of db collection
          collection.find(function(err, res){
            res.toArray(function(err, realRes){
              console.log(realRes);
            });
          });          
   });
```

Comment: I have tried like this, but the consoled object contains huge amount of data and I cant find any result rows inside that data. Is there any particular key that can be called from the res object which holds the result?

Comment: don't we need to close the connection here?

Comment: It is really helpful.